# Процесс не закрывается

Tags: c#, процесс

Не получается закрыть процесс из массива

```
public static void ESA()
{
      foreach (var Files in (new string[] { "*.exe", "*.doc",  }).SelectMany(f => 
      new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)).GetFiles(f)).ToArray())
      {
           foreach (var PC in Process.GetProcessesByName(Files.Name)) // Полагаю что проблема здесь.
           {
               PC.Kill(); // Функция не срабатывает
           }

          Files.Delete(); // Эта функция работает 
      }
}
```

Как можно убить процесс даже когда он открыт, а после закрытия процесса удалить файл?!

Comment: Ошибка вылетает?

Comment: @iluxa1810, нет

Comment: Я не уверен, но , вроде, в имени процесса отсутствует EXE=> ты не попадаешь в цикл.

Comment: Всё верно, не попадаю.

Comment: Самое простое- это получить список всех процессов и посмотреть в дебаггере как выглядят их имена.